# Why doesn't an extern exported function not get exported?

Tags: dll

I have a Visual Studio 2008 solution creating a DLL. It includes a static library. I learned that an exported "__declspec( dllexport )" function in the static library isn't exposed via the DLL.  My current workaround is a definition file.  What I'm wondering is since only the declaration needs the export why can't I have a header in the DLL project with the following:

```
__declspec( dllexport ) function();
```

and in a source file of the static library

```
 __declspec( dllexport ) function() { ...contents... }
```

When the static library is pulled into the DLL shouldn't the definition be resolved with the declaration and the declaration cause the function to be exported?

I tried adding extern to the declaration as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the linker, when building the DLL, will notice that nothing in the DLL calls the function and won't include it in the DLL.  The fact that you're marking it for export doesn't affect the linker's decision.

The usual workaround is to define another function in the same source file as the exported function, and call that function from elsewhere in the same module (eg. DllMain).  That will ensure that the linker includes the module that defines your exported function.

Raymond Chen has a [piece about this on his blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/03/21/10509670.aspx).